# Npgsql (PostgreSQL) F# sample doesn't compile with unresolved assemblies

Tags: f#, csqldataprovider

I'm trying to test out SqlDataProvider in F# for PostgreSQL, but I fail to compile due to some assemblies not loading. I'm experimenting with VS2019, .net core 3.1.

Here are the packages I include. Shouldn't nuget resolve all dependencies?

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Npgsql" Version="4.1.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="FSharp.Data" Version="3.3.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json" Version="3.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="MySql.Data" Version="8.0.18" />
    <PackageReference Include="MySqlConnector" Version="0.61.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL" Version="3.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="SQLProvider" Version="1.1.76" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.Net.Primitives" Version="4.3.1" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

Here's the code:

```
open System
open FSharp.Data.Sql
open Npgsql

let [<Literal>] ConnString1 = "Host=localhost;Port=5431;Database=DB;Username=postgres;Password=PASSWORD"
let [<Literal>] DbVendor = Common.DatabaseProviderTypes.POSTGRESQL
let [<Literal>] ResPath = @"./packages/Npgsql/lib/netstandard3.1"

type Sql = SqlDataProvider<DbVendor,ConnString1,"",ResPath,1000,true>

[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv =
    printfn "Hello World from F#!"
    0 // return an integer exit code
```

Here are the errors:

```
1>------ Build started: Project: ConsoleApp3, Configuration: Debug Any CPU ------
1>D:\valuer\v2\ConsoleApp3\Program.fs(12,12): error FS3033: The type provider 'FSharp.Data.Sql.SqlTypeProvider' reported an error: Unable to load one or more of the requested types. Retrieve the LoaderExceptions property for more information.Details: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Net.Primitives, Version=4.1.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.Could not load type 'System.Runtime.CompilerServices.INotifyCompletion' from assembly 'System.Runtime, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'.Could not load type 'System.IAsyncDisposable' from assembly 'System.Runtime, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'.Could not load type 'System.ICloneable' from assembly 'System.Runtime, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'.Could not load type 'System.Data.Common.DbCommandBuilder' from assembly 'System.Data.Common, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'.Could not load file or assembly 'System.Runtime.Extensions, Version=4.2.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.Could not load type 'System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter' from assembly 'System.Data.Common, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'.Could not load type 'System.Data.Common.RowUpdatingEventArgs' from assembly 'System.Data.Common, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'.Could not load type 'System.Data.Common.RowUpdatedEventArgs' from assembly 'System.Data.Common, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'.Could not load type 'System.IO.Stream' from assembly 'System.Runtime, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'.Could not load file or assembly 'System.Threading, Version=4.1.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.Could not load file or assembly 'System.Transactions.Local, Version=4.0.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.Could not load file or assembly 'System.Collections, Version=4.1.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.Could not load type 'System.ReadOnlyMemory`1' from assembly 'System.Runtime, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'.Could not load type 'System.DBNull' from assembly 'System.Runtime, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'.Could not load type 'System.ValueTuple`2' from assembly 'System.Runtime, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'.Could not load file or assembly 'System.Net.NetworkInformation, Version=4.2.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.Could not load file or assembly 'System.ComponentModel.TypeConverter, Version=4.2.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.Could not load type 'System.Runtime.CompilerServices.IAsyncStateMachine' from assembly 'System.Runtime, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'.Could not load type 'System.Threading.CancellationToken' from assembly 'System.Runtime, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'.Could not load type 'System.Threading.Tasks.ValueTask`1' from assembly 'System.Runtime, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'.
1>D:\valuer\v2\ConsoleApp3\Program.fs(12,12): error FS3033: The type provider 'FSharp.Data.Sql.SqlTypeProvider' reported an error: Unable to load one or more of the requested types. Retrieve the LoaderExceptions property for more information.Details: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Net.Primitives, Version=4.1.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.Could not load type 'System.Runtime.CompilerServices.INotifyCompletion' from assembly 'System.Runtime, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'.Could not load type 'System.IAsyncDisposable' from assembly 'System.Runtime, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'.Could not load type 'System.ICloneable' from assembly 'System.Runtime, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'.Could not load type 'System.Data.Common.DbCommandBuilder' from assembly 'System.Data.Common, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'.Could not load file or assembly 'System.Runtime.Extensions, Version=4.2.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.Could not load type 'System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter' from assembly 'System.Data.Common, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'.Could not load type 'System.Data.Common.RowUpdatingEventArgs' from assembly 'System.Data.Common, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'.Could not load type 'System.Data.Common.RowUpdatedEventArgs' from assembly 'System.Data.Common, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'.Could not load type 'System.IO.Stream' from assembly 'System.Runtime, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'.Could not load file or assembly 'System.Threading, Version=4.1.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.Could not load file or assembly 'System.Transactions.Local, Version=4.0.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.Could not load file or assembly 'System.Collections, Version=4.1.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.Could not load type 'System.ReadOnlyMemory`1' from assembly 'System.Runtime, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'.Could not load type 'System.DBNull' from assembly 'System.Runtime, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'.Could not load type 'System.ValueTuple`2' from assembly 'System.Runtime, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'.Could not load file or assembly 'System.Net.NetworkInformation, Version=4.2.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.Could not load file or assembly 'System.ComponentModel.TypeConverter, Version=4.2.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.Could not load type 'System.Runtime.CompilerServices.IAsyncStateMachine' from assembly 'System.Runtime, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'.Could not load type 'System.Threading.CancellationToken' from assembly 'System.Runtime, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'.Could not load type 'System.Threading.Tasks.ValueTask`1' from assembly 'System.Runtime, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'.
1>Done building project "ConsoleApp3.fsproj" -- FAILED.
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

Comment: One thing I can see, your referencing  System.Net.Primitives version 4.3.1 in your ItemGroup but the error reported is for version 4.1.1 being missing.

Comment: Good catch... However I don't see 4.1.1 in nuget: there's 4.0.12 and 4.3.0, neither helps. Typing 4.1.1 in the fsproj also fails